# Can not connect TFS Server

Tags: visual-studio-2013

These days my VS2013 work and connect TFS server normally. But this morning I uninstall .Net Frameword 4.5.1 then reinstall .net Framework 4.5. After install finished I open VS2013 and connect TFS Server, the message like this occur Team Foundation Error Page '3185...2e50' not found
[image]

Please help me solve this issue. Many thanks

Comment: No, I reinstalled .Net Framework

Comment: Then it's the time for you to reinstall TFS, I mean

Answer (score 2):

Why did you uninstall .Net 4.5.1? It is required by TFS 2013 (check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn641202.aspx#NET)). TFS Object Model (used by VS 2013 to connect to TFS) is built against .NET 4.5.1. I suggest you re-install .Net 4.5.1 to fix it.